# use one session for all subdomains

Tags: php, session

i want use one session for all subdomains

my `php.ini`

```
session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"

[root@bh /]# ls -la /var/lib/php/session
total 48
drwxrwxrwx 2 root   apache 4096 Jul 10 17:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root   4096 Apr 28 11:22 ..
-rw------- 1 sub1 sub1 233 Jul 10 10:30 sess_1ct61gdtjmd2u2chom3eu4h8t4
-rw------- 1 sub1 sub1 233 Jul 10 10:33 sess_4etbc6bh4lqabeve35mr01fp35
-rw------- 1 sub1 sub1 233 Jul 10 10:40 sess_9h62k8h50tkfnf391ji0mj57m4
```

my test file `/home/sub1/public_html/test1.php`

```
<?
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'www.mydomain.com');
session_start();
$_SESSION['test']='test......';
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

my second test file `/home/sub2/public_html/test2.php`

```
<?
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'www.mydomain.com');
session_start();
$_SESSION['test_two']='test......';
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

Now i have browsed both files,

i should get this results

```
array(['test']=>'test......',['test_two']=>'test......')
```

But, nothing happens!!

if i am on sub1.domain.com, i get this result `['test']=>'test......'`

and if i am on sub2.domain.com, i get this result ['test_two']=>'test.....'

Nothing has changed, it's working like a normal

Answer (score 2):

Your current code tries to set the cookie for www.example.com, and you aren't even accessing the site from www.example.com! That's why it isn't working.

You will want to share your session cookie across your entire domain name, like this:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.example.com');
```

Comment: i've replaced .www.domain.com to  .domain.com, it still not work

Comment: @AlaaGamal - in your question, you used `www.example.com`, not `.www.example.com`.  Note the difference, and be precise in your question and your follow-up.  These tiny bits of punctuation are extremely important.

Comment: @ghoti, i have tryied everything, .www.example.com and .example.com and example.com and www.example.com, and still trying with no luck, i have even edited php.ini to session.cookie_domain = .example.com, and still not works, i don't know why!

Comment: I think you've hit the nail on the head.  "Trying everything" is not the solution.  Understanding how the process works lets you pick just one thing, knowing it will work, without ever needing to "try".  Read about [session_set_cookie_params()](http://php.net/session_set_cookie_params) then click the [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11423742/edit) link under your question to provide more detail about new things you have tried, and how their results differ from your original findings.